# Should I invest into upgrading my work computer?

Tags: software-industry

At work I develop iOS applications on a late 2012 Mac Mini. With it's 4GB of RAM the computer has gotten progressively more laggy over time, particularly after I upgraded the operating system to OS X Yosemite.

I have suggested a memory upgrade to my boss but it's being delayed for various bureaucratic reasons. One of them is the fact that the memory will have to be ordered from abroad. My boss is adamant that buying on eBay is risky, despite the fact that there is a money back guarantee.

It's not worth purchasing from local Apple representatives because they are ripping us off. They are charging four times the eBay price, asking for a 50% downpayment and what's more telling us it will take 2-3 weeks.

Right now I have a big project on my hands and I'm expected to deliver it in October. The fact that the iPhone simulator sometimes takes 5 minutes to startup up isn't helping me much.

Is it worth buying the memory myself? And would any of you have chosen this alternative? Apart from the productivity gains, I am thinking that it could still serve me if I'm changing jobs. I could use it to upgrade a laptop computer for example (I don't own a laptop right now).

Comment: If you upgrade your own machine then I wouldn't expect to be able to take the upgrade back whenever you leave the company, e.g. you would have to donate this upgrade to the company machine if you really wanted to do it

Comment: Do you time sheet. Can you make explicit the time you feel is wasted?

Comment: Are you concerned with the apple store pricing or is your boss?  If it's just you, stop messing around and get the memory through proper channels, ie the apple store/rep

Comment: My boss is concerned about the pricing too. The Apple rep asked us to go through their parent company, which represents Apple in my country. That parent company doesn't just deal with Apple products.

Comment: Thanks for your answers everyone. I've already sent an email to my boss to explain the necessity for an upgrade (though I have avoided explicitly asking to extend the project submission date). The good news is that he agrees to it but when I'll be getting it isn't certain. Hopefully in less than 2 months. We will be going through our parent company that's based in France (it's they who supply us funding). In the meantime I am trying to manage as best as I can. Luckily I am not the only person in the team.

Comment: Ebay?! Your boss is right to be concerned about the quality of products, and the real cost of buying them, on an auction site.  Have you considered Newegg instead - which deals in used computer parts and offers good rates?

Comment: "Is it worth buying the memory myself?" - Do you change the oil or replace the tires on a rented car?

Answer (score 29):

**Short answer:** You should not be required to upgrade work equipment at your own expense.

Make a better case to your boss as to why you need it, and if it's convincing they will do it.  If it's that important, the extra dollars from your local Apple representative will be more than covered by the extra productivity lost in time waiting for something to arrive from overseas.

Remember, it's *their* deadlines, if they see enough of a business impact by poor hardware specifications, they will break through the red tape.

Comment: agreed. In order to put this in terms the business can understand, the OP should come up with some rough estimates of the time difference between old and new hardware to perform the same task, and show that as cost in dollars (against billed rate) over an extended period of time. Essentially -- right now the business is paying the OP a lot of money to sit and wait for the hardware to respond.

Comment: You need to be quite forthright.  You are being asked to deliver a product by a certain deadline, but the company won't invest in the money to make it happen.  Either they upgrade you (and I mean really upgrade you, we are talking MacBook PRO top of the line) or you won't make your deadline.  You can't build a skyscraper with a hammer and nails, you need cranes, welders, girders.

Comment: @BillLeeper I agree but many times management just doesn't get it -- they think the developers just want new toys, or don't really believe the performance affects deadlines. That's why it's important to break it down into cost/time terms.

Comment: @Jane S as I mentioned the local Apple representative doesn't have the RAM in stock and want us to wait three weeks (as from the point we make the downpayment). They could even be buying the memory from some online store for all I know.

Comment: @seggaeman That may be possible but it's still your employer's responsibility to provide it however they believe is most appropriate.  Just raise your concerns _in writing_ and leave it to them to manage their own risk :)

Answer (score 5):

You should never bring your own hardware upgrades to company owned hardware unless you get a written permission. In many companies it is forbidden because it can void the warranty (and companies usually pay extra for warranty) and if anything breaks it is your responsibility and you can loose your job.

Show your manager how you are working at this time and explain clearly that this is putting the project at risk so he needs to make a decision whether to:

1. Buy expensive locally
2. Buy on the web
3. Delay the finish date
4. Reduce the content of the project

Comment: Ok those are some good points. Actually the mac mini is already out of warranty for more than a year. The Apple Care protection plan was never subscribed for.

Answer (score 3):

Never do your own upgrade on a work computer, hardware or software.  The following list only begins to show why it's a bad idea:

- You may invalidate any support contract or warranty that your company has
- You may violate company security laws by simply opening the casing of the computer
- You are leaving yourself responsible if this vital computer breaks down during this project
- You are risking the company by installing unsanctioned hardware (what about third party spyware etc)
- What do you do if the boss decides you do need a faster computer and trades it in without your knowledge?
- What do you do if you get fired ("excuse me security man, can you let me go whilst I open this work resource to get my memory back, it really is mine")
- If you are not certified to replace hardware you may stop an insurance pay out if the machine fails.

Etc.

What you do is get some metrics on how long this is holding you up for each day, how much that will cost the company, and the long term effect on delivery of your project. Prepare a report and make sure you have a record of sending it to your boss.  From this it should be a no-brainer for your boss to sanction more memory (or a better computer), even from the expensive local company.  If he reads that and still says no, then you have a bigger problem than just a slow computer, so keep delivering as best you can, but start looking for something new.

Comment: Your list is a bit on the paranoid side. The OP is NOT "risking the company" by installing memory modules. He is risking the memory modules and, if he does it wrong, the embarrassment wrecking a useless 2012 mac mini.

Comment: Really?  Given the main development machine is a 3yr old mac mini, I'd doubt there is source code management etc, so if the machine goes pfft,  so too will the project and maybe the company.  And if you install spyware as part of the upgrade maybe your 40bn WhatsApp killer is leaked

Comment: The first and most important thing to rememeber is that you do not own this machine. You have no right to change it without approval. Most companies that are larger than a  startup witll fire you for this crap because while you may not think your are putting the company at risk, they will. Mostly because it has happened to them  before and caused problems.

Comment: @TheWanderingDevManager, I can't tell if you're being sarcastic about the introduction of spyware via ddr memory modules. I suppose it is possible in a science-fictional sense, if your company is a target for the NSA or Chinese state-sponsored hacks !

Comment: @teego1967 - what I'm serious about is if you put your own personal hardware or software on a work computer and it ends up hacked or with spyware YOU will be the first person blamed, and the (impossible) onus will be on you to prove you DIDN'T cause it.  Seen it happen, so just don't do it.

Answer (score -2):

Sometimes work just won't help you out no matter what you try. Assuming you have gone through all the normal channels and the answer is still "no" - think about it this way:

**Suppose you can pay $100-$200 to magically increase your productivity. Would you?**

That's essentially the question you are trying to answer. You are trading your own money to make yourself faster at work. The fact that work is *supposed* to pay for it is irrelevant. If you don't make the deadline, your boss is not going to blame your computer. He is going to blame you.

Definitely try everything you can to get work to pay for it, but you personally have the most to gain and the most to lose out of this, not anyone else.

Comment: As in any project, this is a risk.  If it's been raised early (before there is an _apparent_ issue) often enough, then you can very easily point out the evidence if it happens to become an actual issue.  It then becomes a _business decision_ whether or not they act on that risk.  If they do not feel it's worth spending the money, then they must own that risk.

Comment: @JaneS That is how it is supposed to work. In reality a lot of bosses are not logical or reasonable.

Comment: I guess you just need to avoid an environment where it becomes _expected_ that the developer will pick up the slack for poor infrastructure management.  What happens when you have the same problem again?  Guess who will have to pay for it again, because management then perceives it as a developer's issue when it is clearly not.

Comment: While I could totally see myself doing this, I don't like this answer at all. What if the RAM was manufactured incorrectly and fries the computer? Okay, maybe not likely but, you could use the same logic to buy yourself a fancy new keyboard that is suppose to increase productivity. That keyboard could be full of nasties (viruses, etc that get installed when plugged in).

Comment: I know many people that use their own keyboard.

Comment: Never bring your own hardware to plug into a company hardware, if anything happens it is your responsibility.

Comment: @Bowen, I know many people who have surreptitiously implanted memory, wifi, key loggers, etc into keyboards and then sold them on eBay to see what juicy details they could get. Okay, I don't really know anyone who has done that, but it wouldn't be hard.

Comment: I like this answer. The company should pay and I would even argue that a 2012 mac mini is not appropriate for development work.However, if the OP needs to get through the next few weeks without pain and without arguing, it won't hurt to upgrade the memory on his own dime-- assuming a memory upgrade will make enough of a difference.

Comment: @mikeazo Yeah I don't think ebay is a good idea.

Comment: -1 - This is extraordinarily bad advice in so many ways.

Comment: By investing your own money into hardware that is not approved by your company, you *definitely* increase what you have to lose by doing this. Not only is it now *your* investment instead of the company, you risk any damage done to the machine, even if it's *not* related to your new hardware, being attributed to you and the onus of it being placed entirely upon your 'tampering'.  I would not recommend this course of action at all.

Comment: This is a great way to get fired.